# SWI-prolog - how to clear terminal screen with a keyboard shortcut or global predicate?

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

I want to clear screen inside SWI-prolog console using either keyboard shortcut or command (i guess in Prolog you call that "predicate").

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16441062/how-to-clear-screen-in-sicstus-prolog) is similar question where i kinda find what i need - there is predicate that works for me:

```
write('\33\[2J').
```

Is there a better (easier) way to clear screen?

Answer (score 8):

On UNIX terminals, you can simply use the built-in `tty_clear` predicate to clear the console.

```
tty_clear.
```

Comment: This doesn't work as I try (v8.4.2, 64-bit, Windows 10).
`?- tty_clear.
ERROR: Unknown procedure: tty:tty_get_capability/3
ERROR: In:
ERROR:   [12] tty:tty_get_capability(cl,string,_3000)
ERROR:   [11] tty:string_action(cl) at c:/program files/swipl/library/tty.pl:82
ERROR:    [9] toplevel_call(user:user:tty_clear) at c:/program files/swipl/boot/toplevel.pl:1158
ERROR: 
ERROR: Note: some frames are missing due to last-call optimization.
ERROR: Re-run your program in debug mode (:- debug.) to get more detail.
   Exception: (12) tty:tty_get_capability(cl, string, _2456) ?`

Comment: This didn't work for me as well. Using SWI-Prolog in windows 64 machine

Comment: Apparently, Windows terminals do not support `tty_clear`, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16908764/clearing-screen-in-swipl-prolog-in-windows) for a Windows alternative, such as `cls :- write('\e[2J').` I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 4):

SWI-Prolog allows the definition of a settings file that is loaded by default at startup. Its name depends on the operating-system. On POSIX systems, it's named `.swiplrc`. You can simply create or update the file if you're already using it with a definition for a shortcut predicate. For example:

```
cls :- write('\33\[2J').
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for helping me. I was able to solve my problem - in the folder, where i have my .pl file, i added file "swipl.ini"(it's for windows), where i added predicate:

```
cls :- write('\33\[2J').
```

Now i can just write inside SWI-prolog terminal "cls." and it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

In 2022, running SWI-Prolog on Windows 10, the initialisation file is called 'init.pl', and is located on my computer in C:\Users\*name*\AppData\Roaming\swi-prolog